# Why does Convert.ToInt32(DateTime) exist?

Tags: c#, .net

Simply curious, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch56d3w9.aspx) says that

> Calling this method always throws
>   InvalidCastException.

So why does this overload exist in the framework? Is it following some sort of pattern? I would assume for backwards compatibility it would be better to remove the overload and receive compile errors rather than run-time exceptions. I don't remember if this method was actually supported in previous frameworks though.

Comment: Well, if this method didn't exist, it would use the `Convert.ToInt32(Object)` overload anyway, which would presumably throw the same exception.

Comment: I'm curious what value you expect to be returned from this method?  (milliseconds won't fit)   Also, the pattern it's following is, I believe, the same methods you find in `IConvertible`.

Comment: @Kirk, I don't think that was my point. I am just asking why it exists, even if you can't use it...

Comment: I know, and my suggestion is that they are following the pattern of methods defined in `IConvertible`.  Take a look:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the documentation in the link you provided:

> **Remarks**
>
> This method is reserved for future
>   use.

They simply haven't found an implementation they are happy with or is necessary, but they are planning for it to be so.

Comment: actually I don't see the Remarks in my link..hmm..but regardless why have it in the Framework if there is no use for it at the moment?

Comment: @Stan R. - You know you're right. My browser automagically sent it to the 2.0 version. The remark is there. My assumption is that it is still relevant today since the implementation is identical. In response to your other question, only the implementation team of this object can truthfully tell you, but I suspect the other answers have not missed the mark by much if at all.

Comment: I agree, I am just saying it's like introducing "dynamic" keyword in 2.0 and saying it's for future use..it just wouldn't make sense right?

Comment: @Stan R. - the sensibility really falls down to intent. I've put method implementation requirements in interfaces before that I had no intention of immediately implementing but that I knew I would need later. When I added those implementations, I was glad of having prepared for it. I'd say the sensibility of it eventually comes down to intent. Do they REALLY intend to implement it or are they just teasing us and satisfying some unnecessary interface constraint?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that IConvertable requires this to be implemented.

Comment: I think the static method calls the instance method on the parameter that is passed into it, i.e. Convert.ToInt32(IConvertible obj)

Comment: @poindexter: Correct; it does.  However, it still shouldn't exist.

Comment: @SLaks: Sort of agree.  It sucks that it does, but it has to in order to adhere to the contract.  Would you rather the exception existed or never be able to convert a DateTime to anything?

Comment: It's a static method.  It **doesn't** need to exist; there is no contract for statics.

Comment: That static class does just take a DateTime, but under the covers I think it is using the IConvertible.ToInt32(), which must be implemented by DateTime.  I assume this is actually what throws the exception.

Comment: This is pretty correct IMO.  Convert is a helper class to invoke the IConvertable implementations on the standard value types.  DateTime indeed implements it and throws the exception.  The only one that doesn't throw is IConvertable.ToDateTime().  It isn't so much that Convert *requires* it to be implemented, it ought to in order to keep symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it just calls [DateTime.IConvertible.ToInt32 Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299767.aspx) which is in turn responsible for throwing that exception. One day it will do the conversion and `Convert.ToInt32(DateTime)` will work without any change!

Comment: Until that day, it's just a subtle bug.  Besides, they can always add that overload later.

Answer (score -1):

They simply put it in the documentation, nothing special. If this does not exist, the same condition can be:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Object)
```

Comment: that's not the same condition..you can pass *string* to ToInt32(Object) which would work, but not DateTime, that would make sense to me, but they have a distinct overloaded method that just doesn't work.